# How to get the correct number of distinct combination locks with a margin or error of +-2?

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to solve the usaco problem combination lock where you are given a two lock combinations. The locks have a margin of error of +- 2 so if you had a combination lock of 1-3-5, the combination 3-1-7 would still solve it.

You are also given a dial. For example, the dial starts at 1 and ends at the given number. So if the dial was 50, it would start at 1 and end at 50. Since the beginning of the dial is adjacent to the end of the dial, the combination 49-1-3 would also solve the combination lock of 1-3-5.

In this program, you have to output the number of distinct solutions to the two lock combinations. For the record, the combination 3-2-1 and 1-2-3 are considered distinct, but the combination 2-2-2 and 2-2-2 is not.

I have tried creating two functions, one to check whether three numbers match the constraints of the first combination lock and another to check whether three numbers match the constraints of the second combination lock.

```
a,b,c = 1,2,3
d,e,f = 5,6,7
dial = 50

def check(i,j,k):
    i = (i+dial) % dial
    j = (j+dial) % dial
    k = (k+dial) % dial
    if abs(a-i) <= 2 and abs(b-j) <= 2 and abs(c-k) <= 2:
        return True
    return False

def check1(i,j,k):
    i = (i+dial) % dial
    j = (j+dial) % dial
    k = (k+dial) % dial
    if abs(d-i) <= 2 and abs(e-j) <= 2 and abs(f-k) <= 2:
        return True
    return False

res = []
count = 0
for i in range(1,dial+1):
    for j in range(1,dial+1):
        for k in range(1,dial+1):
            if check(i,j,k):
                count += 1
                res.append([i,j,k])
            if check1(i,j,k):
                count += 1
                res.append([i,j,k])

print(sorted(res))
print(count)
```

The dial is 50 and the first combination is 1-2-3 and the second combination is 5-6-7.

The program should output 249 as the count, but it instead outputs 225. I am not really sure why this is happening. I have added the array for display purposes only. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since `dial % dial == 0`, `(i+dial) % dial` is just a verbose way to write `i % dial`. Your intent in that code is not clear (especially since it refers to global variables which are not defined in the code that you provide). Please give a [mcve].

Comment: How is 249 the correct answer?  Simple combinatorics gives 225.

Comment: @Prune where did 225 come from? 2*5**3 = 250. In my reading of the (somewhat unclear) question, the 249 answer comes from 3-4-5 being counted twice (once in the shadow of 1-2-3 and once in the shadow of 5-6-7).

Comment: Ah ... I see ... I didn't read correctly the dual-combination interaction.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to a lot of trouble to solve this by brute force.

First of all, your two check routines have identical functionality: just call the same routine for both combinations, giving the correct combination as a second set of parameters.

The critical logic problem is handling the dial wrap-around: you miss picking up the adjacent numbers.  Run `49` through your check against a correct value of `1`:

```
# using a=1, i=49
i = (1+50)%50   # i = 1
...
if abs(1-49) <= 2 ...   # abs(1-49) is 48.  You need it to show up as 2.
```

Instead, you can check each end of the dial:

```
a_diff = abs(i-a)
if a_diff <=2 or a_diff >= (dial-2) ...
```

Another way is to start by making a list of acceptable values:

```
a_vals = [(a-oops) % dial] for oops in range(-2, 3)]
```

... but note that you have to change the `0` value to `dial`.  For instance, for a value of `1`, you want a list of [49, 50, 1, 2, 3]

With this done, you can check like this:

```
if i in a_vals and j in b_vals and k in c_vals:
    ...
```

---

If you want to upgrade to the `itertools` package, you can simply generate all desired combinations:

```
combo = set(itertools.product(a_list, b_list_c_list) )
```

Do that for both given combinations and take the union of the two sets.  The length of the union is the desired answer.

---

I see the follow-up isn't obvious -- at least, it's not appearing in the comments.

- You have 5*5*5 solutions for each combination; start with 250 as your total.
- Compute the sizes of the overlap sets: the numbers in each triple that can serve for each combination.  For your given problem, those are `[3],[4],[5]`
- The product of those set sizes is the quantity of overlap: 1*1*1 in this case.
- The overlapping solutions got double-counted, so simply subtract the extra from 250, giving the answer of 249.

For example, given 1-2-3 and 49-6-6, you would get sets

```
{49, 50, 1}
{4}
{4, 5}
```

The sizes are 3, 1, 2; the product of those numbers is 6, so your answer is 250-6 = `244`

Final note: If you're careful with your modular arithmetic, you can directly compute the set sizes without building the sets, making the program *very* short.

Comment: Interesting how you are saying it would be harder to solve this by brute force. I was looking at other blogs relating to this problem, and they say the easiest solution is to solve it by brute force.

Comment: @Krish If the tolerance is much smaller than the number of dial settings, a brute-force which enumerates through all possible combinations is very inefficient. Prune's answer (+1) *is* a form of brute-force, but it is *smart* brute force -- iterating through all valid combinations rather than all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for what you are trying to do is the following:

```py
dial = 50
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 5
e = 6
f = 7

def check(i,j,k):
    if  (abs(a-i) <= 2 or (dial-abs(a-i)) <= 2) and \
        (abs(b-j) <= 2 or (dial-abs(b-j)) <= 2) and \
        (abs(c-k) <= 2 or (dial-abs(c-k)) <= 2):
        return True
    return False

def check1(i,j,k):
    if  (abs(d-i) <= 2 or (dial-abs(d-i)) <= 2) and \
        (abs(e-j) <= 2 or (dial-abs(e-j)) <= 2) and \
        (abs(f-k) <= 2 or (dial-abs(f-k)) <= 2):
        return True
    return False

res = []
count = 0
for i in range(1,dial+1):
    for j in range(1,dial+1):
        for k in range(1,dial+1):
            if check(i,j,k):
                count += 1
                res.append([i,j,k])
            elif check1(i,j,k):
                count += 1
                res.append([i,j,k])

print(sorted(res))
print(count)
```

And the result is 249, the total combinations are 2*(5**3) = 250, but we have the duplicates: `[3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Interesting, but the correct solution is 249 according to USACO. The only overlapping number is 3-4-5. 3-4-4 cannot even be a duplicate as you would need to subtract 3 from the 7 from the second combination lock. You can only have an a maximum absolute difference of two.

Comment: you are right, I put the wrong numbers for the combination using [4, 5, 6] instead of [5,6,7]

Comment: fixed, the result is 249

Comment: This solution fails when the dial is 10, the first combo is 9 9 9, and when the second combo is 3 3 3. I think I might need to add a clause where if the combinations have a difference greater than 2, it skips the loops and just outputs 249.

Comment: you were right there was a bug in the code, now it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to a semi-brute-force solution:

```
import itertools

#The following code assumes 0-based combinations,
#represented as tuples of numbers in the range 0 to dial - 1.
#A simple wrapper function can be used to make the
#code apply to 1-based combos.

#The following function finds all combos which open lock with a given combo:

def combos(combo,tol,dial):
    valids = []
    for p in itertools.product(range(-tol,1+tol),repeat = 3):
        valids.append(tuple((x+i)%dial for x,i in zip(combo,p)))
    return valids

#The following finds all combos for a given iterable of target combos:

def all_combos(targets,tol,dial):
    return set(combo for target in targets for combo in combos(target,tol,dial))
```

For example, `len(all_combos([(0,1,2),(4,5,6)],2,50))` evaluate to 249.